# C# Azure Mobile Service Backend / JS Client 405 Error

Tags: azure

anyone have any idea how to enable CORS in the context of C# Backend Mobile Service being invoked by a JS function via the MS Azure Mobile Services JS library?? I get 405 and have looked at this link (https://gist.github.com/HenrikFrystykNielsen/6c934be6c6c8fa9e4bc8) which makes sense but no longer applies.

Mobile Services written in JS can be configured for CORS via the portal, but not C# backends.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in the gist still applies -- remember to load the CORS NuGet package as well.

Henrik

Comment: I just added the custom ConfigBuilder. The EnableCors method is invoked, but the JS code in my MVC app still receives a 405

Comment: Turns out adding the custom config builder and adding  [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] to the mobile service method made the 405 go away. Thanks Henrik!

Comment: You should add the "adding [EnableCors("", "", "*")] " as the accepted answer